# How to populate the values in a response object array data using *ngFor in Angular

Tags: arrays, angular, spring, typescript, object

I want to display data coming from a backend Api in Angular using *ngFor.But data is coming as an object  which contains an array of size 10.This the image of the backend response that shows in `console.log(hotels);` [image]

This is the angular code which i have written in component.ts file

```
   hotelInfo = [];
   hotelInfo2 = [];

    getTopHotelInfo() {
        const params = [];
        params.push({code: 'dateType', name: 'CHECKIN'});
        params.push({code: 'fromDate', name: '2018-01-01'});
        params.push({code: 'toDate', name: '2019-01-01'});
        params.push({code: 'topN', name: 10});
        this.dashboardServiceHandler.getTopHotelInfo([], params).subscribe(
          hotels => {
            console.log(hotels);
            this.hotelInfo.push(hotels);
            console.log(this.hotelInfo);
            for (let i = 0; i < this.hotelInfo.length; i++) {
                const hotel = this.hotelInfo[i];
                console.log(hotel);
                /// this.hotelInfo2.push(hotels[i]);
                this.hotelInfo2.push({code: hotel.code, name: hotel.name});
                console.log(this.hotelInfo2[i]);
            }
         });
      }
```

This is the code which i have written in component.html file

```
<li *ngFor="let hotel of hotelInfo">
        <div class="c-inbox-widget__item">
          <div class="c-inbox-widget__item__avatar" style="background: #A3A1FB">
            01
          </div>

            <div>
              <span class="c-inbox-widget__item__author">{{hotel.name}}</span>
              <!--<span class="c-inbox-widget__item__text">Canada</span>-->
            </div>

            <div class="c-inbox-widget__item__value">$29,193</div>

        </div>
   </li>
```

How could I get those data as an array to *ngFor

Comment: What's the role for hotelInfo and hotelInfo2?

Comment: @Mridul hotelInfo @ hotelInfo2 are arrays.I 'm trying to get the console.log as an array

Comment: Why are you running for loop ?

Comment: You just need to show the results coming in response irrespective of their size?

Comment: It 's coming as an object.Only arrays are allowed in *ngFor

Comment: Your response seems to be like `{ responseObj: [ { } ] }`

Comment: @Mridul Yes.But I could n't show data in front end

Comment: I 'm running a for loop to get data in to an array one by one.

Comment: you directly use in for loop like in ts file `this.hotelInfo = hotels` and html file `*ngFor="let hotel of hotelInfo.responseObj"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way. your response is an object and it contains an array with key `responseObj`.

```
getTopHotelInfo() {
        const params = [];
        params.push({code: 'dateType', name: 'CHECKIN'});
        params.push({code: 'fromDate', name: '2018-01-01'});
        params.push({code: 'toDate', name: '2019-01-01'});
        params.push({code: 'topN', name: 10});
        this.dashboardServiceHandler.getTopHotelInfo([], params).subscribe(
          hotels => {
            console.log(hotels);
            this.hotelInfo = hotels.responseObj;
         });
      }
```

Now run ngFor on `hotelInfo`. It should work as per your response.

Example:

```js
let obj = {
      responseObj: [
        { name: 'a' },
        { name: 'b' },
        { name: 'c' }
      ]
    };
    
    console.log(obj.responseObj);
```

Comment: Great. Happy to help :).

Answer (score 1):

You could use **keyValue** pipe in angular

```
  <div *ngFor="let hotel of hotelInfo">
    <div *bgFor="let q of hotel | keyvalue>
           {{q.key}} - {{q.value}}
    </div>
  </div>
```